# Interop.word serviço

Tags: c#, wcf

Boa tarde, estou utilizando a microsoft.office.interop.word para converter documentos word em pdf em WCF, contudo a interopr simplesmente para funcionar o WCF fica online só a interopr não funciona, aonde é necessário restartar o serviço  de WCF para ele voltar a funcionar.

Alguém tem ideia o que pode ser?

Comment: Mas tens algum erro? "não funciona" o que significa?

Comment: Significa que o serviço fica online mais a interop não funciona a rotina que convert word para pdf atravéns da interop, não retorna erro e quando restar o  wcf volta a funcionar.

Comment: Para ajudar seria interessante que você colocasse o que está tentando fazer e qual mensagem de erro ocorre. Podem ter centenas de motivos.

Comment: E o código de onde vc está utilizando o interop? Melhora essa explicação ai, senão fica difícil né!

Answer (score 0):

Talvez possa ser um conflito da versão do site, usando Interop você deve rodar sua aplicação como 32bits.  Configure no pool de aplicação do IIS pra executar a aplicação como 32 bits. O servidor deve ter instalado a versão do office que você esta usando o Interop também.

Após usar o Interop, você deve liberar o objeto.

```
try
{
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(msWordDoc);
    msWordDoc = null;
}

catch (Exception exReleaseObject)
{
    msWordDoc = null;
    //   Console.WriteLine(CMSResourceFile.REALESE_FAILED+ exReleaseObject);

}
finally
{
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}
```

Talvez essa resposta te ajude.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44544295/keeping-one-interop-office-application-alive-until-iis-restart-for-all-users-i

Comment: Então aplicação web chama um serviço WCF que fica responsável pela interop.